# How to modify the content-length post modification of response in a middleware in FastAPI?

Tags: python, middleware, fastapi, asgi, starlette

Example Code:

```py
# Here is a minimal reproducible example

import json
from starlette.datastructures import MutableHeaders
from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Receive, Scope, Send, Message
import datetime
import socket
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

class MetaDataAdderMiddleware:
    application_generic_urls = ['/openapi.json', '/docs', '/docs/oauth2-redirect', '/redoc']
    
    def __init__(self, app: ASGIApp) -> None:
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:

        start_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        async def send_wrapper(message: Message) -> None:   
         
            if message["type"] == "http.response.body" and len(message["body"]) and not any([scope["path"].startswith(endpoint) for endpoint in MetaDataAdderMiddleware.application_generic_urls]):

                response_body = json.loads(message["body"].decode())

                end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                response_processing_time_seconds = end_time - start_time
                data = {}
                data["data"] = response_body
                data['metadata'] = {
                    'request_timestamp_utc': start_time,
                    'response_timestamp_utc': end_time,
                    'processing_time_seconds': response_processing_time_seconds,
                    'service_host': socket.gethostname()
                }

                data_to_be_sent_to_user = json.dumps(data, default=str).encode("utf-8")
                message["body"] = data_to_be_sent_to_user

            await send(message)
        await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)


app = FastAPI(
    title="MY DUMMY APP",
)

app.add_middleware(MetaDataAdderMiddleware)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Description:
So here is my usecase: All of my endpoints in FastAPI APP, whatever response they are sending, I need  to wrap that response, with some metadata. Let's say, some endpoint is sending me this: `{"data_key": "data_value"}`. But, the users should see, this as the final output:

```json
{
    "data": {"data_key": "data_value"}
     "metadata": {
          "request_timestamp_utc": "somevalue",
          ...and so on
     }
}
```

I have a big application, and numerous routers. We have achieved the functionality of adding Request ID, Authentication and Authorization, so far by writing middlewares.

However, when I hit APIs of my app, after adding the abovementioned MetaDataAdderMiddleware, I am greeted with this following error:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<MY PYTHON PATH>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 521, in send
    raise RuntimeError("Response content longer than Content-Length")
RuntimeError: Response content longer than Content-Length
```

This error is logical enough, since I have modified the Response body but not changed the content-length headers.

Here is snapshot of message and scope bodies in the send_wrapper function level, and as well as header values I have printed from the httptools_impl.py level:
(I have edited out some fields, to mask org-specific things)

```
send_wrapper called
message: {'type': 'http.response.start', 'status': 200, 'headers': [(b'content-length', b'58'), (b'content-type', b'application/json')]}
scope: {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.1'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'scheme': 'http', 'method': 'POST', 'root_path': '', 'query_string': b'', 'headers': [(b'content-type', b'application/json'), (b'accept', b'*/*'), (b'cache-control', b'no-cache'), (b'accept-encoding', b'gzip, deflate'), (b'content-length', b'238'), (b'connection', b'keep-alive')], 'app': <fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at >, 'fastapi_astack': <contextlib2.AsyncExitStack object at >, 'router': <fastapi.routing.APIRouter object at >, 'endpoint': <function initiate_playbook_execution at >, 'path_params': {}, 'route': <fastapi.routing.APIRoute object at >}
INFO:     - "POST /MYAPI" 200 OK

INSIDE httptools_impl
name: b'content-length' | value: b'58'
self.expected_content_length: 58

send_wrapper called
message: {'type': 'http.response.body', 'body': b'{"status":true,"stdout":null,"stderr":null,"message":null}'}
scope: {'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.1'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'scheme': 'http', 'method': 'POST', 'root_path': '', 'query_string': b'', 'headers': [(b'content-type', b'application/json'), (b'accept', b'*/*'), (b'cache-control', b'no-cache'), (b'accept-encoding', b'gzip, deflate'), (b'content-length', b'238'), (b'connection', b'keep-alive')], 'app': <fastapi.applications.FastAPI object at >, 'fastapi_astack': <contextlib2.AsyncExitStack object at >, 'router': <fastapi.routing.APIRouter object at >, 'endpoint': <function initiate_playbook_execution at >, 'path_params': {}, 'route': <fastapi.routing.APIRoute object at >}

INSIDE httptools_impl
body: b'{"data": {"status": true, "stdout": null, "stderr": null, "message": null}, "metadata": {"request_timestamp_utc": "BLAH", "response_timestamp_utc": "BLAH", "processing_time_seconds": "0:00:00.469472", "some_field": "some_value"}}'
num_bytes: 286
```

Here are the attempts that I have made to update the content-length:

- In the send wrapper function just after I update the response body, I have tried doing the following:

  ```py
  data_to_be_sent_to_user = json.dumps(data, default=str).encode("utf-8")
  message["body"] = data_to_be_sent_to_user
  headers = MutableHeaders(scope=scope)
  headers["content-length"] = str(len(data_to_be_sent_to_user))

  # But this hasn't worked, no change in situation!
  ```

How can I proceed forward?

Comment: Have you looked at how Starlette's GZipMiddleware does it? They have the same requirement where the content-length changes: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/fcc4c705ff69182ebd663bc686cb55c242d32683/starlette/middleware/gzip.py#L60

Comment: Hey thanks for this, though I couldn't understand much of the solution, what I broadly understood was: it stops the http.start message from going, first finds out the length from http.body; then sends both these messages one after another. I implemented borrowing heavily from the example you gave and it worked. Adding detailed answer below.

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting an answer as well detailing how you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MatsLindh comment, I referred to Starlette's GZipMiddleware codebase here: https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/fcc4c705ff69182ebd663bc686cb55c242d32683/starlette/middleware/gzip.py#L60

So the idea is, the problematic `content-length` value is in header present in `http.response.start` message. So, how GZipMiddleware has been written is, they have simply not sent this first `http.response.start` message instantly. Instead, they also capture `http.response.body`, then modify the response, then find its length, then update the length in `http.response.start` message, and then send both these messages in the correct order.

The working implementation that I was able to write, borrowing heavily from GZipMiddleware  is here:

```py
from starlette.types import ASGIApp, Receive, Scope, Send, Message
from starlette.requests import Request
import json
from starlette.datastructures import MutableHeaders


class MetaDataAdderMiddleware:
    application_generic_urls = ['/openapi.json', '/docs', '/docs/oauth2-redirect', '/redoc']
    
    def __init__(
            self, 
            app: ASGIApp
    ) -> None:
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:
        if scope["type"] == "http" and not any([scope["path"].startswith(endpoint) for endpoint in MetaDataAdderMiddleware.application_generic_urls]):
            responder = MetaDataAdderMiddlewareResponder(self.app, self.standard_meta_data, self.additional_custom_information)
            await responder(scope, receive, send)
            return
        await self.app(scope, receive, send)


class MetaDataAdderMiddlewareResponder:

    def __init__(
            self,
            app: ASGIApp,
    ) -> None:
        """
        """
        self.app = app
        self.initial_message: Message = {}

    async def __call__(self, scope: Scope, receive: Receive, send: Send) -> None:
        self.send = send
        await self.app(scope, receive, self.send_with_meta_response)

    async def send_with_meta_response(self, message: Message):

        message_type = message["type"]
        if message_type == "http.response.start":
            # Don't send the initial message until we've determined how to
            # modify the outgoing headers correctly.
            self.initial_message = message

        elif message_type == "http.response.body":
            response_body = json.loads(message["body"].decode())

            data = {}
            data["data"] = response_body
            data['metadata'] = {
                'field_1': 'value_1',
                'field_2': 'value_2'
            }

            data_to_be_sent_to_user = json.dumps(data, default=str).encode("utf-8")

            headers = MutableHeaders(raw=self.initial_message["headers"])
            headers["Content-Length"] = str(len(data_to_be_sent_to_user))
            message["body"] = data_to_be_sent_to_user

            await self.send(self.initial_message)
            await self.send(message)
```

Comment: hello it gives me this error  
AttributeError: 'MetaDataAdderMiddleware' object has no attribute 'standard_meta_data' 
can you please help me how to solve this issue.